# webdriver thread available through the whole project

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I managed to run my tests in parallel with different browsers and for now it looks fine
I create my driver in @BeforeTest section and kill it in @AfterTest, the threads are fine ( one for every browser) ,  started and stopped fine
I have a lot of functions in different classes that uses my driver so, I wonder if there is some way to "share" it to the whole project 
I know I can just pass the driver as parameter to other classes but would be easier in the other way :-)

Any suggestion ?

```
Public class Test1 {

            protected static  WebDriver driver;

            @BeforeTest
            @Parameters({ "browser", "HUBip" })
            public void launchBrowser(@Optional("FF") String browser, @Optional("localhost") String HUBip) throws MalformedURLException {

                try {
                     if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) { 
                            DesiredCapabilities caps=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                            driver=new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(url, caps);

                        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) {
                            DesiredCapabilities caps=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                            driver=new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(url, caps);
                        } else {
                            DesiredCapabilities caps=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                            driver=new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(url, caps);    
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

            @Parameters("browser")
            @Test(testName="Quick SMS SmokeTest",description="Smoke test 'Quick SMS'section", groups="SmokeTest")   
            public void quickSMS_SmokeTest(@Optional("IE")  String browser) throws Exception {              
                try {   
                    LogIn(driver,ObjectsPaths.ADMIN_USER,ObjectsPaths.ADMIN_PASSWORD);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Reporter.log("from exception" + e.toString());          
                }
            }

            @AfterTest
            public void closeBrowser() throws Exception {
                driver.quit();
            }



        <suite name="Automated Tests" verbose="2" preserve-order="false" parallel="tests" alwaysRun="true" thread-count="2">
        <test name="Test1FF" preserve-order="true">
                    <parameter name="browser" value="ff" ></parameter> 
                        <classes>

                        <class name="com.AutoTest.test.Test1" />

                        </classes>          
        </test> 


        <test name="Test1IE" preserve-order="true">


                    <parameter name="browser" value="ie" ></parameter> 
                        <classes>   
                        <class name="com.AutoTest.test.Test1" />            
                        </classes>

        </test> 
        </suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented to maintain one webdriver for the entire suite is like below:

```
public class TestCaseOne extends TestSuiteOneBase{
//This contains the methods and classes for the test cases
@BeforeTest
@Test
@Test
@AfterTest
}

public class TestSuiteOne extends TestSuiteManager{
//some common methods to be used across the suite
}

public class TestSuiteManager{
//preCondition methods
//Driver is declared here so it's visible across all other objects.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this but no luck ! what i see when i make something like this, is that both browsers start but only one run the test case, the other seems to be frozen:-(

Comment: Need to see your code, cause I'm currently using the above implementation. The driver has to be declared as a public variable, initialized within a function in the parent (suitemanager) class. It will be available for use in other classes.

Comment: I agree it will be available to other classes in this way but,  if I have a parallel execution, the driver will be also created in multiple instances? This is the part i'm not sure to understand  :-)